# Initializing an object with a lot of variables from String values

Tags: java, excel, constructor

I am makung a company Web-Application where you can upload an Excel-File and convert one of its Sheets into a JSON text. For this I use a class where each object represents one row from said sheet, where each variable of the object is one column. It's a large Excel-File with a lot of Columns, so there a lot of variables.

```
public class MetaDataRow {

private String deleted = "";
private String bo_name = "";
private String typeKey = "";
private String category = "";
private String descriptor = "";
private String group_name = "";
private boolean Zusatzobjekt = false;
private String group_layout = "";
private boolean collapsed = false;
private boolean visibleInCreationMode = true;
private int group_gridSize = 12;
private int groupPosition = 1;
private int maxCount = 1;
private String fachID = "";
private String name = "";
private String attributeName = "";
private String format = "";
private String fieldType = "";
private String dependentField = "";
private String controllLogicOfDependentField = "";
private String dependentValidationFormat = "";
private String length = "";
private String rangeMin = "";
private String rangeMax = "";
private String dateRangeMin = "";
private String possibleValues = "";
private String werteliste = "";
private String defualtValue = "";
private String fachbereiche = "";
private boolean visible = true;
private boolean editable = true;
private boolean pflichtfeld = true;
private boolean genehmigungspflichtig = true;
private String tooltip = "";
private boolean filterAttribute = true;
private boolean showInSearchResults = true;
private int position = 1;
```

The problem is that the Excel Files do not always have the same order of columns in the sheet, so I have to read out the names of the columns and initialize the fields one by one.
What would be an efficient way to do this? Would it maybe be possible to make some sort of "General-Setter" where you can choose which variable to set based on a String, e.g.

`public void setter(String fieldName, Object content) { Variable with name fieldname = content; }`

If that doesn't work, what are your suggestions?

Comment: Does "read out the names of the columns" mean that e.g. the first Excel row contains column names? And are these column names identical to the JSON field names?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a General Setter I found

```
        private void callSetter(Object obj, String fieldName, Object value){
          PropertyDescriptor pd;
          try {
           pd = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, obj.getClass());
           pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(obj, value);
          } catch (IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
```